# Not able to see web element when I navigate to page using Automation

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, browser-automation, uiautomation

I have a web page which displays a new contact creation button. When I try to navigate to a page through automation, I can not see that button. When I login to site manually and navigate to same page, I can see that button.

I have tried almost all wait times and page load scenarios.

Just want to know what is the issue here. The user that I am using for logging in through manually/automation is same

Comment: Welcome to the community. We would need more info to provide a meaningful answer. What's the web page? Can you provide screenshots of both situations?

Comment: Additionally to what Lee said, browser console logs would be interesting (and talk to the developer :D)

Comment: Could you try this functionality in incognito mode in your browser? Because I think it's a cache problem